# Searching for video titles on YouTube with Node.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm creating a bot for Discord and I stumbled upon this. How do you (using a given string) search for a video on youtube and get its URL?

I'd prefer if you gave me some lite library on [NPMJS](https://www.npmjs.com/).

Sorry if I'm being a little uninformative but tl;dr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [youtube-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-node) NPM package. You'll need to get your API key from Youtube before you can start using this package.